# Windows Explorer in Windows 7 is misbehaving

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

If I start typing, after just two or three characters, it highlights what I typed and erases it with whatever I type next. The windows don't respond to clicks, even minimize or close buttons. They eventually work but not right away. Even moving the window makes it slide back right away. This is a new install of Windows 7 Ultimate x64 that was working fine before I installed hundreds of initial Windows Updates. Now I can hardly use Windows Explorer or the Control Panel. For example, if want to edit Firewall settings, I start typing "firewall" but I can only do about the first three characters before it's all wiped out. At first I thought this was Control Panel only but I see all Explorer windows acting this way. They seem to be refreshing every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Windows due to this. Had enough and didn't want to deal with such weirdness.

Comment: I was the OP. I just stated what I did with my problem.